# How to deploy django project in Mac Pro Server?

Tags: django, django-deployment

I just got a new Mac Pro Server. This is first time I am deploying a project to my server. I know how to deploy to heroku. Can I just download django and run the website? Any information on this would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/

Comment: @SeanMcSomething Thanks for the reply. I already looked up the documentation. I was wondering if I could find any other website with all the security measures I have to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do run my servers is using Django, Nginx, supervisord and gunicorn. You can read about how to implement it in several blogs out there, this one for example [Setting Up Django With Nginx, Gunicorn, Virtualenv, Supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

You will need to adapt it to Mac OS but using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) that's super easy.

Comment: Thanks @julio. That really helps. What server do you run your projects on?

Comment: Usually Ubuntu running on a VPS in [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=5db5e81c9668). They are really cheap, you get a 512MB of memory, 20GB of SSD storage and 1TB of bandwidth for $5 per month. And their support rocks!!